# Combinations of cards out of a deck with sets

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

> I have a deck of $25$ cards, $10$ of them are identical to each other, and the other $15$ are made of $5$ sets of $3$ identical cards for visualisation:
>
> $10$ black, $3$ green, $3$ red, $3$ yellow, $3$ blue, $3$ pink
>
> If I draw $10$ cards randomly, how many different hands can I draw?

I tried using my combinatorics knowledge but it wasn't enough, the answer itself is less important to me but the actual way is what I'm after here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'different hand'?

Comment: A hand is 10 cards that you draw. if i draw 10 cards, look at them and then put them back and draw again, over over and over, how many different combinations of 10 cards are possible.

Comment: I understand now. I thought about poker hand.

Comment: @dvd280 Okay, I posted an answer with something of a general method... but it isn't much better than brute force, it just puts everything in math terms. You still won't be able to do it by hand.

Comment: If you "draw... and then put them back and draw again", this is called sampling with replacement.  The question of "how many different hands can I draw" is then rather simple to answer, because it is possible to get any combination or permutation of the six colors.  Are you sure this is the right interpretation (putting the cards back in the deck)?

Comment: No this is not, i just simplified because he was thinking of different interpertations of hands. i just want to know how many different combinations there are for a 10 card draw out of this 25 card deck. forget the replacement stuff- there is no replacement- i mentioned it just so he could understnad what i meant by different hands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the generating function $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10})$$ and look at the co-efficient of the $x^{10}$ term.  This generating function could be written as $$\left(\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^5 \dfrac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}$$

I get $1 + 5 + 15 + 35 + 65 + 101 + 135 + 155 + 155 + 135 + 101 = 903$ distinct  hands though these are not equally like.

Comment: Cool!  So much faster than my brute force method ... is there a good page explaining why this works?

Comment: thanks for this, but i dont really understand how the function gave us those numbers...

Comment: @Bram28 *generatingfunctionology* at https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: @dvd280 try multiplying out $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$ and look at the co-efficients

Comment: @Henry Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Let $x_b$ be the number of black cards, $x_{\color{blue}{b}}$ be the number of blue cards, $x_g$ be the number of green cards, $x_r$ the number of red cards, $x_p$ be the number of pink cards, and $x_y$ be the number of yellow cards.  Then the number of hands with ten cards is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_b + x_{\color{blue}{b}} + x_g + x_p + x_r + x_y = 10 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that 
\begin{align*}
x_b & \leq 10\\
x_{\color{blue}{b}}, x_g, x_p, x_r, x_y & \leq 3
\end{align*}
Since we only have ten cards in our hand, the condition $x_b \leq 10$ cannot be violated.  However, up to two of the remaining five conditions can be violated.  It is not possible to violate three of them since $3 \cdot 4 = 12 > 10$.

If there were no restrictions, a particular solution of equation 1 would correspond to the placement of five addition signs in a row of ten ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 + + 1 1 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_b = 4$, $x_{\color{blue}{b}} = 2$, $x_g = 1$, $x_p = 0$, $x_r = 3$, and $x_y = 0$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can insert five addition signs in a row of ten ones, which is 
$$\binom{10 + 5}{5} = \binom{15}{5}$$
since we must choose which five of the fifteen positions (for ten ones and five addition signs) will be filled with addition signs.

From these, we must exclude those cases in which one or more of the restrictions are violated.

Suppose $x_{\color{blue}{b}} > 3$.  Then $x_{\color{blue}{b}} \geq 4$.  Let $y_{\color{\blue}{b}} = x_b - 4$.  Then $y_{\color{blue}{b}}$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $y_{\color{blue}{b}} + 4$ for $x_b$ in equation $1$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_b + y_{\color{blue}{b}} + 4 + x_g + x_r + x_p + x_y & = 10\\
x_b + y_{\color{blue}{b}} + x_g + x_r + x_p + x_y & = 6 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{6 + 5}{5} = \binom{11}{5}$$
solutions.  By symmetry, there are equal number of solutions in which one of the other four restrictions is violated.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{11}{5}$$
cases in which one of the restrictions is violated.

However, if we subtract $\binom{5}{1}\binom{11}{5}$ from $\binom{15}{5}$, we will have counted those cases in which two of the conditions are violated twice, once for each way we counted one of the colors as violating the restriction.  Since we only want to subtract them once, we must these cases back.

Suppose $x_{\color{blue}{b}} > 3$ and $x_g > 3$.  Let $y_{\color{blue}{b}} = x_{\color{blue}{b}} - 4$ and $y_g = x_g - 4$. Then $y_{\color{blue}{b}}$ and $y_g$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $y_{\color{blue}{b}} + 4$ for $x_{\color{blue}{b}}$ and $y_g + 4$ for $x_g$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
x_b + y_{\color{blue}{b}} + 4 + y_g + 4 + x_p + x_r + x_y = 10\\ 
x_b + y_{\color{blue}{b}} + y_g + x_p + x_r + x_y & = 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{2 + 5}{5} = \binom{7}{5}$$
solutions.  By symmetry, each of the $\binom{5}{2}$ cases in which two of the five restrictions are violated results in an equal number of cases.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{5}$$
cases in which two of the restrictions are violated.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ten card hands that can be formed is 
$$\binom{15}{5} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{11}{5} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{5}$$

Comment: This gives the same $903$ as my answer

Answer (score 3):

Yikes ... the only way I can think of is just brute force, where I have 11 major cases (from 10 to 0 black cards), and then subcases for each:

- $10$ black cards: $1$ option
- $9$ black cards:  $5$ options (since $5$ colors) for $10$th card
- $8$ black cards: Two subcases here for the remaining two cards:

$8A$. Same color for $2$ remaining cards ($5$ options)

$8B$. Different colors for those $2$ cards (so pick $2$ out of $5$ colors: ${5 \choose 2}=10$.

So total of $15$ options with $8$ black cards

- $7$ black cards:  For remaining $3$ cards, there are $3$ subclasses:

$7A$: all $3$ remaining cards are same color ($5$ options)

$7B$: $2$ out of remaining $3$ have same color, last one is different: $5*4=20$ options ($5$ options for the color of the $2$ cards, and $4$ choices for the last card)

$7C$: all $3$ remaining cards are different color: ${5 \choose 3}=10$ options

Total for case $7$: $35$ options

- $6$ black cards:

$6A$: $3$ same color, $1$ different: $20$ options

$6B$: $2$ same color + $2$ same color: $10$ options

$6C$: $2+1+1$: $5*{4 \choose 2}=5*6=30$ options

$6D$: $1+1+1+1$: ${5 \choose 4}=5$ options

Total of $65$ options for case $6$

- 5 black cards:

$5A$: $3+2:20$

$5B$: $3+1+1:30$

$5C$: $2+2+1:30$

$5D$: $2+1+1+1:5*{4\choose3}=5*4=20$

$5E$: $1+1+1+1+1$: $1$ option

Total for $5$: $101$

etc ... ( I think you will now have seen how to handle the different cases)

EDIT

Alright .. I hate leaving answer incomplete ...

- $4$

$4A$: $3+3:10$

$4B$: $3+2+1: 5*4*3=60$

$4C$: $3+1+1+1: 5*4=20$

$4D$: $2+2+2: 10$

$4E$: $2+2+1+1: 10*3=30$

$4F$: $2+1+1+1+1: 5$

Total: $135$

- $3$

$3A$: $3+3+1: 10*3=30$

$3B$: $3+2+2: 5*6=30$

$3C$: $3+2+1+1: 5*4*3=60$

$3D$: $3+1+1+1+1: 5$

$3E$: $2+2+2+1: 10*2=20$

$3F$: $2+2+1+1+1:10$

Total: $155$

- $2$:

$2A$: $3+3+2: 10*3=30$

$2B$: $3+3+1+1: 10*3=30$

$2C$: $3+2+2+1: 5*6*2=60$

$2D$: $3+2+1+1+1: 5*4=20$

$2E$: $2+2+2+2: 5$

$2F$: $2+2+2+1+1:10$

Total: $155$

- $1$

$1A$: $3+3+3: 10$

$1B$: $3+3+2+1: 10*3*2=60$

$1C$: $3+3+1+1+1: 10$

$1D$: $3+2+2+2: 5*4=20$

$1E$: $3+2+2+1+1: 5*6=30$

$1F$: $2+2+2+2+1: 5$

Total: $135$

- $0$

$0A$: $3+3+3+1: 10*2=20$

$0B$: $3+3+2+2: 10*3=30$

$0C$: $3+3+2+1+1: 10*3=30$

$0D$: $3+2+2+2+1: 5*4=20$

$0E$: $2+2+2+2+2: 1$

Total: $101$

Total total: $1+5+15+35+65+101+135+155+155+135+101=\boxed{903}$ possible hands

Comment: oh ok, and what if i changed the question to 25 cards, 3 are undesired and 22 are desired,  what are the odds of getting 3 undesired in a 10 card draw?

Comment: @dvd280 That question is a good bit different.  Different question -> different post!

Comment: @dvd280 I think what the OP is getting at is that he/she wants a non-brute force general method to attack more complicated problems like this.

Comment: @Nilknarf Yeah, I wish I knew of one ... what a pain! :)

Comment: Since 3 of 10 cards must be undesired, we must choose cards for rest 7 places. We can do this on binomial(22, 7) ways. All possible choices for a hand of 10 cards are binomial(25, 10). So ratio of this values 6 / 115 are your odds.

Comment: You have missed $5$ cases when there are $3$ blacks, which should have a total of $155$ equal to the number when there are $2$ blacks

Comment: @Henry  Good eyes!  I just spotted that one myself ... and a few more ... :(  I think I got them all now though!

Comment: $903$ indeed seems to be correct

Comment: This problem is easier to handle with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle (see my answer) or generating functions (see Henry's answer).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, *much* easier!  Good to know!